# Android accessibility: how to change the search bar readed string

Tags: android, kotlin, search, accessibility, talkback

as I wrote in the title, the Android Talkback actually reads the hint text of my search bars, but I need to change that behavior to read a custom string (different from the hint). I tried to set the contentDescription but it didn't work (the talkback still reads the hint text).

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an `AccessibilityDelegate` on a view to override things like how it describes itself in general:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(yourView, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat(){
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View?, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat?) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
        info?.let { it.text = "whatever" }
    }
})
```

or you can override `onPopulateAccessibilityEvent` (which handles triggered events like `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED`) and use `event.getText()`, which gives you a `List<CharSequence>` you can `add` your description to. It really depends on what you're doing and how dynamic it needs to be.

I haven't found a good overview of all this stuff unfortunately, otherwise I'd link you to it. I think the delegates are what you need to look into though